# use selector search on html code(string) on PHP variable or ways alike

Tags: php, html, string, io

what im currently doing is i have a text area for user to copy and paste the html code. 
i want to get a certain element of that html file.
in pure html, this can be done via jquery selector
but i think its a whole different thing when html code is on a variable and considered as a string. 
how can i get a certain element location in that way?

code is:

```
        function searchHtml() {
            $html = $_POST; // text area input contains html code
            $selector = "#rso > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > h3 > a"; //example - the a element with hello world
            $getValue = getValueBySelector($selector);  //will return hello world     
        }
        function getValueBySelector($selector) {
            //what will i do here?
        }
        searchHtml();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at SimpleHTMLDom Parser (manual at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). This is a powerful tool to parse the HTML code to find and extract various elements and their attribute.

For your particular case, you can use

```
// Create a DOM object from the input string
$htmlDom = str_get_html($html);
// Find the required element
$e = $htmlDom->find($selector);
```

Oh, and you've to pass the provided input value to the getValueBySelector() function :-)

Comment: i... never... thought.. that there is something like that.. out there. im quite shock. i think that will solve my problem! ill give it a test first. once verified, ill mark this as the correct answer. :) thanks a ton!

Comment: glad to help @JosephBada, do let know in case you need further help with it!